# Using ST_Intersection with two rasters?

Tags: postgis, raster, intersection

I need to query all values in `raster A` which intersect with `raster B`.

Found this, but it's not accurate, and I'm getting `ERROR:  column reference "rast" is ambiguous`.

```
WITH first AS (
   SELECT id, (ST_Intersection(rast, rast, 0)).val
   FROM file_caolvkddzzlgmvyeofrh
   INNER JOIN file_xbwnbydpmwesokzmrcht ON ST_Intersects(rast, rast, 0)
)
SELECT id, COUNT(val), SUM(val), AVG(val), stddev(val), MIN(val), MAX(val)
FROM first
GROUP BY id;
```

This is probably very wrong - but basically, I need to figure out how to get all values of `raster A` that intersects with `raster B`.

Comment: ST_Intersects( raster rastA , raster rastB ); http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Intersects.html

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
select row_to_json(t) from (
    SELECT A.rid, pvc 
    FROM rasterA A 
    JOIN rasterB B 
    ON ST_Intersects(A.rast, B.rast), 
       ST_ValueCount(A.rast,1) 
    AS pvc
) as t;
```